# how to fix Javascript unexpected token illegal

Tags: javascript, push-notification, syntax-error

I am getting an error in the following code on the first line:

```
if (typeof module != ‘undefined’ && module.exports) {
  module.exports = PushNotification;
}
```

This is the error:
[image]

I cannot seem to find the syntax error here. I am trying to use PushPlugin for iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you copy-pasted out of a rich text document and it inserted smart quotes:

```
‘undefined’
```

Replace them with regular quotes:

```
'undefined'
```